# Android: if statement not working with .isPlaying()

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I created an onClick methord PlaySound in which an if statement checks weather the sound is playing or not , if it is playing it stops it or else it starts it.The problem i face is that the if statement is always false and never true.

**CODE**

```
public void PlaySound(View view) {
    final MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abcd);

    if(clickSound.isPlaying()) {
        clickSound.stop();
    }
    else{
        clickSound.setLooping(true);
        clickSound.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your debugger and see if anything suspicious pops out.

Comment: Tried it already.Every thing is fine

Comment: it start playing the sound again

Comment: You are creating a new instance of a MediaPlayer every time that method gets called so ofc isPlaying returns false.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: By not creating a new instance of a MediaPlayer every time the method is called? There's an answer saying that right below...

Comment: you can't get the previous state of instance while creating new everytime

Comment: I don't get the downvotes: the question is well done. It is not the most difficult question out there but it is clearly written, has a code sample and a clear problem statement. Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
final MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abcd);
```

from `play` method and create it outside of the method.

**Edit** for your convenince follow the steps:

You can take a global variable of MediaPlayer

```
 public  MediaPlayer clickSound ;
```

and then create in `onCreate` method:

```
clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abcd);
```

and thus your `play` method will be:

```
public void PlaySound(View view) {

    if(clickSound.isPlaying()) {
        clickSound.stop();
    }
    else{
        clickSound.setLooping(true);
        clickSound.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried creating it out side.Gives error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: @VedSarkar have you created in onCreate method?

Comment: it was giving error before when i tried to declare clickSound outside....your solution is working like charm